# QuickSight, Automatically Add Large Number of Columns to Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, dashboard, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight

**Is there a way to automatically add a large amount of columns to a QuickSight table without the manual procedure of draging and dropping them?**

For instance in the picture below: I would like to add all numbered columns to the table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The QuickSight support said that **this is not possible for now**. They have received this question multiple times and it will hopefully be possible in the future.